# How would I order a table by the number of matching params in the where clause of an sql statement?

Tags: sql, parameters, matching

I'm writing sql to search a database by a number of parameters. How would I go about ordering the result set by the items that match the most parameters in the where clause. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username = 'eitan' 
OR email = 'eitan@eitan.com' 
OR company = 'eitan'


Username   |  email                |   company

1) eitan   |     blah@blah.com     |     blah

2) eitan   |     eitan@eitan.com   |    eitan

3) eitan   |    eitan@eitan.com    |     blah
```

should be ordered like:

2, 3, 1.

Thanks. (ps the query isn't that easy, has a lot of joins and a lot of OR's in the WHERE)

Eitan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
ORDER BY 
    (username = 'eitan') 
    + (email = 'eitan@eitan.com') 
    + (company = 'eitan') 
    DESC
```

If PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
ORDER BY 
    (username = 'eitan')::int 
    + (email = 'eitan@eitan.com')::int 
    + (company = 'eitan')::int 
    DESC
```

If Sql Server:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
ORDER BY 
    case when username = 'eitan' then 1 else 0 end
    + case when email = 'eitan@eitan.com' then 1 else 0 end
    + case when company = 'eitan' then 1 else 0 end
    DESC
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that. Well, something else I've learnt today.

Comment: I think the OP would still like to have the `WHERE username = 'eitan' OR email = 'eitan@eitan.com' OR company = 'eitan'` clause

Comment: yeah i know, but that's the best that could be done, he just need to add that WHERE clause.  afaik, there's no construct yet that can weigh the truthiness of WHERE clause

Comment: You can still add the WHERE clause can't you with the ORDER BY can;t you?

Comment: yeah must be added.  but to minimize the noise in the code, i only show the proof-of-concept code for doing math on booleans, everything else is corollary